# How to load Jquery Datatables in div with Coldfusion Navigate

Tags: jquery, html, coldfusion, datatables

I have a problem loading a jquery datatable in a

`<div id="loadcontainer" name="loadcontainer"></div>`  with coldfusion.navigate

```
<a onClick="ColdFusion.navigate('school_create.cfm','loadcontainer');">
     Add School Details
</a>
```

The page (school_create.cfm) runs well but the table does not have the effect of the jquery in it ( i mean the table shows in a normal way unlike the jquery table). But when i run the the page (school_create.cfm) without the `<div` container, it runs well.

Please, i will need your help as soon as possible! Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I tried adding a callback by doing this (just for testing) but when i click the link, it doesn't load.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    var mycallBack = function(){ 
        document.getElementById("loadcontainer").innerHTML = "<br><br><b>This is printed by the callback handler.</b>"; 
    }  
</script>

<a href="javascript:ColdFusion.navigate('school_create.cfm?theVariables','loadcontainer', mycallback);"> 
    Add School Details
</a>
```

Comment: you need to use the callback to run your script. see docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fd0.html

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your quick response. I am a noob when it comes to javascript. How do i set my call back? Thanks. Expect from you.

Comment: @Bob0101 Please, kindly explain how you did yours.. I noticed you overcame the problem.